# Function method for average numbers

Tags: java

```
public class Part4 {
   public static void main(String args []) {
      Random rand = new Random();
      int total = 0;
      for(int i = 0;i< 10;i++) {
         total += rand.nextInt(101);
      }
      double avg = (double) total/10;
      System.out.println("The average of 10 marks is " +avg);
   }
}
```

My code works perfectly, however I don't know how to put my code in the procedure method. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Please edit your question to more explicitly state what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @voidHead, is that fine now

Comment: @CharanSingh what exactly do you want the method to do ?

Comment: @Moh123, basically i want teh method to calculate the average of 10 random numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're at a very early stage of learning Java, so I thought I'd pop in an even 'simpler' solution.

```
public class Part4
{

   //This is the method you need to call
   public static double calculateAverage(int amount) {  
       Random rand = new Random();
       int total = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
           total += rand.nextInt(101);
       }
       double avg = (double) total / amount;
       return avg;
   }

   public static void main(String args []) {
       //And this is how we call it
       double avgRes = calculateAverage(10)
       System.out.println("The average of 10 marks is " +avgRes);

   }
}
```

Thanks to Moh123 and Mosa, I borrowed some code.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this. You can say with parameter amount with how many number you want to calculate the average.

```java
public double calculateAverage(int amount) {  
    Random rand = new Random();
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        total += rand.nextInt(101);
    }
    double avg = (double) total / amount;
    System.out.println("The average of 10 marks is " + avg);
    return avg;
}
```

Comment: Mosa when i run your program i doesn't give me an option to run the program, is it ebcause there are supposed to be two signatures

Comment: It's because @Moh123 gave the full solution. This is a perfect answer, if you have some basic knowledge of how functions work. Moh's is better when you have none.

Answer (score 2):

The following example shows how to delegate the calculations to a method , how to call it by instantiating the class Part4

```
public class Part4
{
   public double getAvgRandNum(int num)
   {
      Random rand = new Random();
      int total = 0;
      for(int i = 0;i< num ;i++)
      {
        total += rand.nextInt(101);
      }

      double avg = (double) total/num;

      return  avg;

   }

   public static void main(String args []) {

   Part4 prt = new Part4()

   double avgRes = prt.getAvgRandNum(10)

   System.out.println("The average of 10 marks is " +avgRes);

   }
}
```

In Main we are instantiating (creating an object of) class Part4.Once an object is created "prt" just use the dot operator to access (call) its method getAvgRandNum.

Comment: if you are doing java you have write things in a class. How do you think you will call the method that @Mosa has proposed

Comment: hers is not complicated

Comment: can u explain the lines after public static void main (String args[])

Comment: Also, if u don't mind can u like simply it little bit?

Comment: its as simple as it should be. Have added some explantion. If you are doing java (which is object oriented in nature as opposed to c which is procedural) there is no escaping use of classes and objects

Comment: Thats how you access a objects members. You need to work on your java basics.